# Can I install a signal handler for Boost unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, signal-handling

I've got a lot of Boost unit tests. I can't find the place where I should put my signal handler. There's no `main()` function in the files in unit tests directory. It seems that `main()` is hidden in some macros.

In `unit_test.hpp` I see:

```
namespace boost { namespace unit_test {

int BOOST_TEST_DECL unit_test_main( init_unit_test_func init_func, int argc, char* argv[] );

}
```

But how can I implement my own `main()` function, to be able to set a signal handler there?

Comment: You can disable the main function generation and provide your own one. An example is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_no_main.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As per the instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/single_header_customizations/entry_point.html), you can provide your own `main` function to set the signal handler in. Here is some code adopted for this:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE custom_main
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signalHandler(int sig)
{
    std::cerr << "Inside signal handler" << std::endl;
}

namespace utf = boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1)
{
  BOOST_TEST(false);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);
    return utf::unit_test_main(init_unit_test, argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to force boost unit tests output names of all tests it runs? Google unittests have options -v. But it doesn't work for boost unittests. Thx.